# Error in SOQL Query

Tags: apex, soql

I am trying to form the required query as

```
String searchValueFromUser = '\'' + String.escapeSingleQuotes(searchKey) + '%\''; 
String recordType = '\'Legal_Entity\'';
String sQuery = 'SELECT Id, Name,RecordType.developerName FROM ' +sObjectApiName+ ' WHERE Name LIKE '+searchValueFromUser+' AND RecordType.developerName =: '+recordType+' LIMIT 5';
```

But getting the below error as

> System.QueryException: Only variable references are allowed in dynamic
> SOQL/SOSL.

Comment: Remove the colon before the record type concatenation, or actually use bindings, rather than telling SOQL you have a binding variable named after the record type name. You should use bindings wherever possible since this simplifies your code and avoids SOQL injection vulnerabilities.

Comment: Aftre removing i am getting  System.QueryException: line 1:69 no viable alternative at character '%' -- Error

Comment: That's because you didn't put quotes in the SOQL query around the search value. Again, if you make this a binding you remove this messing around. [Read up on this](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_dynamic_soql.htm).

Answer (score 0):

If you print the query string, you'll see something like

```
SELECT Id, Name,RecordType.developerName
FROM Object
WHERE Name LIKE 'something%' AND 
RecordType.developerName =: 'Legal_Entity' <<< Here's the error
LIMIT 5
```

`=: 'string'` is not a valid syntax for [variable binding](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_SOQL_variables.htm), that's why you got that error.

If you want bind a variale, as you should if it's a dynamic value, instead of string concatenation (`RecordType.developerName =: '+recordType+'`) you should just use the variable name inside the string (`RecordType.developerName =: recordType`), therefore you should also remove the extra single quote you put in `recordType` since they are not needed with variable binging, so `String recordType = 'Legal_Entity';`.

You should leverage variable binding for LIKE too:

```java
String searchValueFromUser = searchKey + '%'; 
String recordType = 'Legal_Entity';
String sQuery = 'SELECT Id, Name, RecordType.DeveloperName FROM ' + sObjectApiName + ' WHERE Name LIKE :searchValueFromUser AND RecordType.DeveloperName =: recordType LIMIT 5';
```

If `sObjectApiName` comes from a user input, you should escapeSingleQuotes there:

```java
String searchValueFromUser = searchKey + '%'; 
String recordType = 'Legal_Entity';
String sQuery = 'SELECT Id, Name, RecordType.DeveloperName FROM ' + String.escapeSingleQuotes(sObjectApiName) + ' WHERE Name LIKE :searchValueFromUser AND RecordType.DeveloperName =: recordType LIMIT 5';
```

Comment: You should cover the mistake with the `searchValueFromUser` in the original as well...